# Using a query and tick boxes to auto fill another tab

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query, vlookup

I'm new to this and I'm racking my brains over how to get this to work, I can do basic `IF` & `Vlookup` but I believe I need the merge the 2 for this one.

Is there a formula I can use on the "NLN" tab that will drag across all the data from the "R&MCollections" tab once the Tick-box on column `P` is True?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]! We can't view your Sheet without requesting access, and I don't like giving out my email address to random strangers on the Internet :)

Comment: Hi Glorfindel I know it's not much but I've added 2 screenshots of the spreadsheet is that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use the following query formula:

```
=QUERY('R&MCollections'!J1:Q," SELECT * WHERE P = TRUE ")
```

*(you can change ranges to your needs)*

**IMPORTANT**
Normally, when referring to text, the `WHERE` clause should be wrapped with single quotes `'   '`
But, **when the clause depends on a Tick box, we MUST NOT use the single quotes**.

As an example:
If one would look for John the `WHERE` clause should be `WHERE P = 'John'`

Functions used:

- [`QUERY`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343)

Comment: Welcome. Please remember that as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, you should [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it so others can benefit as well.

Comment: marikamitsos you are an absolute star, thank you.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to accept. 
Please remember that you can even [upvote](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) the answer. Your upvote will show up later, once you reach [enough reputation](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up) points.